# zsh handling of arguments

Tags: zsh

In the zsh programming language,

how do I get the entire list of arguments as a string in "" ?

i.e. in

```
myzshcommand 1 2 3 foo bar
```

I want something to match me "1 2 3 foo bar"

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `$@`?

Comment: Actually the question could also be understood to mean "give me a _single_ string with all args". That would be `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`.